# Unslider + jquery mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile, unslider

So, I found this amazing plugin called [Unslider](http://unslider.com/), but it seems to dissapear on jquery mobile. I'm trying to implement the basic example. Here's my code:

html:

```
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">

   <script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>    
   <script src="js/vendor/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>  
   <script src="js/vendor/unslider.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/vendor/jquery.event.swipe.js"></script> 
   <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div data-role="page" id="firstPage">

        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <div class="banner">
                <ul>
                    <li>This is a slide.</li>
                    <li>This is another slide.</li>
                    <li>This is a final slide.</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

main.css:

```
.banner { position: relative; overflow: auto; }
.banner li { list-style: none; }
.banner ul li { float: left; }
```

main.js:

```
$(document).on("ready", function () {
    $('.banner').unslider();
});
```

But nothing displays (when combined with other jquery mobile pages). When I use only one page, the unslider is shown as a normal list.

How can I make this work?

Comment: There is no element in your html with the class "initInstructionsSlider"

Comment: Insted of `$('.initInstructionsSlider').unslider();` write  `$('.banner').unslider();`

Comment: thanks @SreekeshOkky , but actually that was a copy-paste error, I was replacing the class name for clarity and I missed the .js part

Comment: @ezabaw Your slider is working fine right now isn't it.

Comment: No, it isn't... :( in my file everything is with the .initInstructionsSlider class, I changed it to .banner for clarity in the post (but missed the .js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I kept trying this until I got it working.

First, I had to add the call into the `pageshow` event:

```
$(document).delegate("#firstPage", "pageshow", function () {
    $('.banner').unslider();
});
```

Then, I had to add some extra css for the `li` elements appear:

```
.banner { 
  position: relative; 
  overflow: auto; 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.banner ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 300%;
}
.banner li { 
  list-style: none; 
}
.banner ul li { 
  display: block;
  float: left; 
  min-height: 350px;
  padding: 4em 0 4px;
  width: 33%;
}
```

I think `min-height` alone does the trick, but I added some more css to style it.

Also, I added the following to make the dots appear:

```
.banner .btn, .banner .dot {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3));
  -moz-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3));
  -ms-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3));
  -o-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3));
  filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3));
}

.banner .dots {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 20px;
}
.banner .dots li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 0 4px;

  text-indent: -999em;

  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;

  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: .4;

  -webkit-transition: background .5s, opacity .5s;
  -moz-transition: background .5s, opacity .5s;
   transition: background .5s, opacity .5s;
}
.banner .dots li.active {
  background: #fff;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue is that you called `unslider` on the wrong/undefined DOM element

There is no DOM element with `class='initInstructionsSlider'` in your HTML

Insted of

```
$('.initInstructionsSlider').unslider();
```

write

```
$('.banner').unslider();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UmtkY/)

Comment: Thanks for your help! It didn't worked for me, but your jsFiddle gave me lights to find the answer :)